# My domain doesn't resolve sometimes, pointing to my own dns server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, domain

I have a domain registered on 1and1.com,

mydomain.com DNS settings are pointing to my own DNS server

```
DNS 1: mypc.no-ip.org
DNS 2: mypc.no-ip.org
```

For DNS server I use SimpleDNS software, because my server is windows based due is a gameserver

This is my settings:

```
mydomain.com A my.ip.number TTL 259200 (3days)
www.mydomain.com CNAME mydomain.com TTL 259200 (3days)
etc.
```

All my subdomains and main domain use the same TTL.

I use no-ip.org in case my IP changes, but my IP it never changed, and I have open DNS port (53)

everything works ok, but to time to time, the domain lose their IP, and can not be resolved, first I though was regarding it wasn't entirely spread across the internet, but I have this domain and settings for several months , and still happening this problem, something the domain/subdomains doesn't not resolved

I tried using Linux based setup (bind) but still happening, any clue what is this happening?

Maybe this is due to no-ip? Should I point directly to my pc with the IP?

Comment: Is there any reason you're running a domain server at all, does this game require it? Usually thats best left to your domain name provider unless you have the hardware & skill to run it properly. You shouldn't ever be running a DNS server for external resolution on a non-static IP address & DNS1 and 2 should be different IPs at the very least with two servers for RFC compliance. (At any rate DNS is 53 on tcp & udp not 52!)

Comment: Everything in a home network setting is [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on [SF].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be pointing mydomain.com directly at my.ip.number as that changes and every time it does, you have to change it manually, and it will take about 3 days for it to propagate across the internet.

Instead just point it at mypc.no-ip.org. This might be one of the times when it's worth just using a CNAME on mydomain.com (using a CNAME on a second-level domain like mydomain.com prevents you from setting other records like MX though).